# Реализация методоа в шаблонных класах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как для класса:

```
template <class T>
class cFunction {
public:
    cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n);
    T getFunc(int num);
private:
    T* func;
};
```

сделать реализацию метода(конструктора например)

Такая конструкция не работает:

```
template <class T>
cFunction <T>::cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
        func[i] = new T(args->getA(), args->getB(), args->getX());
    }
}
```

Зато работает инлайн вставка:

```
template <class T>
class cFunction {
public:
    cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
            func[i] = T(args->getA(), args->getB(), args->getX());
        }
    }
    T getFunc(int num);
private:
    T* func;
};
```

Как правильно писать реализацию без использования инлайн вставок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ (gcc-4.3.4), с присваиванием возиться не стал http://ideone.com/FxVNKd

```
#include <iostream>

class cArguments
{ 
    public:

    cArguments(int,int,int)    {}
    int getA(){return 0;}
    int getB(){return 0;}
    int getX(){return 0;}

};

template <typename T>
class cFunction {
public:
    cFunction(){}
    cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n);
    T getFunc(int num);
private:
    T* func;
};

template <typename  T>
cFunction<T>::cFunction(cArguments* args, int _n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _n; i++) {
        /*func[i] =*/ new T(args->getA(), args->getB(), args->getX());
    }
}

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cArguments arg(10,10,10);

    cFunction<cArguments> a(&arg, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: косях еще в том, что если я это делаю в одном файле с прототипом класса (в h-нике к примеру, или как у вас), то все отлично, а если вынести реализацию в cpp-шник, то опять не находит реализацию

Comment: И не найдёт потому, что при компиляции другого файла он не может породить частную реализацию метода, потому как неизвестно для какого типа она нужна, поэтому реализацию шаблонных функций надо всегда держать в хедерах, за исключением явного указания аргументов шаблона.